# Multidimensional Central Limit Theorem

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

Let $\mathbf{U}^n = (U_1^n,U_2^n,\cdots, U_k^n) $ converge in distribution to $N(\mathbf{0},\Sigma)$.  My question is that if $V_{k+1} \sim N(0,1)$ and is independent of $\mathbf{U}^n$ then is it true that 
$$
(\mathbf{U}^n,V_{k+1}) \stackrel{D}\to N(0,\Sigma') \quad \text{where} \quad \Sigma' = \begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & 1
\end{bmatrix}?
$$

If so, can I generalize this to $(\mathbf{U}^n,V_{k+1},\cdots, V_{k+m}) \stackrel{D}\to N\left(0,\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma &\mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{0} & I_m\end{bmatrix}\right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. This can be validated by the so-called Cramer-Wold device. Given any $a = (a_1^T, a_2^T)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{k + m}$, denote $V = (V_{k + 1}, \ldots, V_{k + m})^T$. By condition and the property of multivariate normal distribution, we have
$$a_2^T V \sim N(0, a_2^Ta_2)$$
and $a_2^TV$ is independent of $U^n$. Therefore, by $a_1^TU^n \Rightarrow N(0, a_1^T\Sigma a_1)$ and the independence between $a_1^T U^n$ and $a_2^TV$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
a_1^T U^n + a_2^T V \Rightarrow N(0, a_1^T\Sigma a_1 + a_2^Ta_2) = N(0, a^T\Sigma'a)
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$. By Cramer-Wold device, this means
$$\begin{bmatrix}U^n \\
V\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow N(0, \Sigma').$$